# Find an element in Iframe and hide it by Jquery or js in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="check1">
<iframe src="xxxx" id="testIframe">
   <div>
      <div>
        ...
         <img class="centered-image" ... >
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
</iframe>
```

Target html structure is in Wordpress, then how to check it exist and hide iframe by jquery or js? below code did not worked. I want to handle it invisibly if target element not exist.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("centered-image").length == 0) {
        $(this).contents().find("#finn-api").hide();
    }
});
```

**Modified:** 
I got a answer as below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    if($("#check1").contents().find(".centered-image").length == 0) {
        $('#finn-api').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `hasclass` Capitalization often matters in programming.

Comment: `this` within the `document.ready` handler will be the `window`, not whatever element you've expecting it to be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, so do you know how to do?

Comment: You are doing is subject to the same origin policy
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This should be the
reason why you are getting permission denied type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1 : You are using `iFrame` and jQuery is written in parent screen

> You are doing is subject to the same origin policy
>   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This should be the
>   reason why you are getting permission denied type errors.

Problem 2 : You might not use `document.ready` function, because it may still loading iframe's content inside. to you need extra element like `button`  or `setInterval()` to check the content inside `iframe`

However you can do this using below code:

```js
function checkImage(){

 if($("#iFrame1").contents().find("#someDiv img").hasClass("centered-image"))
 {
  $("#iFrame1").hide();
 }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iFrame1" height="100%" width="100%" style="min-height:300px;border:none" src="ddl__School.html"></iframe>

<button onclick="checkImage()">Check class in side iFrame</button>
```

And your iframe file html code will be:

```html
<div>
 <div id="someDiv">
  ...
  <img class="centered-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random">
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Use developer tool bar to check the class is applying.